# Data bind a Radio Button to a Yes/No Data field in Acces

Tags: c#, ms-access

I Recently learned that not only can you use sql statements to manage data in your database, but you can also use the "Databindings" Property of a form control to either show or edit the data. However if you have a Yes/No field in you database, how would you go about to use 2 radio buttons to edit the Yes/No field? Will it work if you only assign the "Yes" radio button's Databinding property to the field, that way if it is not checked the fields has a "No" value and a "YES" value if it is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 2 radio buttons :) in a radio group, in this way the deselection of the other one is made automatically :)